# using functional expressions as eventhandlers in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, events

```
const templateTwo = (
    <div>
    <h1>Count :{count}</h1>
    <button  className="button" onClick={minusOne}>-1</button>
    <button onClick={function name() {
      console.log("nnn")
    }}>Reset</button>
    </div>
)
```

1) According to the JSX

```
You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX.
```

2) but while reading docs for eventHandler in React i came across the following

```
 JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.
```

3) Until here  everyThing looks great but now in my above code i had used functional statement as EventHandler but it worked i am confused as per docs we have to use functional expressions inside {}

4) How it worked can we use functional statments inside {} (in jsx )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, `function name() { }` could be either a function declaration *or* a function expression.

```
var a = function name() { };  // <-- function expression

function name() { }           // <-- function declaration
```

JSX expects an expression within the `{}` here, so it is interpreted as a function expression.

You could also do this, with an arrow function (which is surely more common):

```
<button onClick={() => {
  console.log("nnn")
}}>Reset</button>
```

For all intents and purposes this is essentially the same as your version with the `function` keyword.

Comment: So you mean if i pass a functional  statment also it evaluates to  functional expression correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh I'm not really sure what you mean by "functional statement". Contexts that expect an expression will treat `function name() { }` as an expression because that is valid syntax for a function expression.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong  i am referring to functional Declartion  as functional statement

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh Ok. As I said above, that syntax could be a declaration or an expression depending on the situation. In this situation, it's an expression. This is not something that is specific to React.

Comment: Thanks  i read many some documents (in javascript) they divided both  but i didn't notice that they can be declartion or expression (can you provide me any docs)

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh MDN documentation: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), JavaScript.info: [here](https://javascript.info/function-expressions)

Comment: ok expression is someThing that resolves to some value  when ever onClick is fired my function is resolved to some value so it can be consider as expression is it correct

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh I'm not really sure how to illuminate it any further, but I think you're getting bogged down in terminology. The point of the matter is that to use an event handler, you need to give it a function.  This could be an arrow function: `onClick={() => { ... }}`, an old-style function: `onClick={function () { ... }}`, or a function you've defined elsewhere: `onClick={functionDefinedElsewhere}`. That's more or less all you need to know. If you intend to use `this` inside the event handler, an arrow function may be the best choice, but that is a whole other topic.

Answer (score 1):

The code you use is an expression.

```
// Function declaration:
function doStuff() {};

// Function expression:
const doStuff = function() {}
```

So, you're using a function expression and works just fine as others:

```
onClick={function name() {console.log("nnn")}}
```

Read more about [function expression](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-to-use-a-function-declarations-vs-a-function-expression-70f15152a0a0/).

---

Further more,

This statement is invalid:

```
<a onClick={const doStuff = function doStuff(){console.log('nnn')}}>test</a>
```

This expression is valid:

```
<a onClick={doStuff = function doStuff(){console.log('nnn')}}>test</a>
```

The function statement is related to variable hoisting while function expression is related to resolving value. So, you can use anything in jsx that resolves the value.

Comment: Thanks it means anyThing in {}  in jsx will resove to value  so we can use  anything (functional Statment or functional Ecpression)if we don't resove to value then it is a problem